# Which shake sensor has the highest “movement” sensitivity?

Tags: switches, sensor, position-sensor

I bought some shake sensors (switches), the SW-18010P and the SW-18020P to use in a project that would make a device leave its stand-by state when it’s moved from a stationary position (over the table)

But when testing (both of them) connected to an Arduino, they don’t behave the way I wanted. They can’t “sense” the device being lifted slowly from over the table, or moved in my hand when walking.

They do work if I shake it with a lot of force.

I wanted something more sensitive, gentle, that could detect the slightest movement, from laying still over the table to being lifted or moved around, without any shake or jerkiness.

Is there any simple shake sensor that is that sensitive, even to a gentle tilt?

I tried connecting the sensors either in an analog pin (one leg on Arduino 5V and the other on the analog input) and also one leg in a digital pin with pullup enabled and the other leg in ground.

Both gave me the same results.

My device is a dual slave flash with a common battery-power source. When it´s laying flat on the table, I´d like it to enter stand-by mode. If I get it to use it, I´d like it to automatically leave stand-by state. The controller (and battery case) is really small, and I lack internal space to fit more stuff than I already have... A shake sensor is really small, that´s why I preferred this route, rather than using an accelerometer.

Cost isn´t a huge deal as it´s only one unit, but internal space in my enclosure is. That´s the main reason I tried this kind of small sensor.

[Here is the original datasheet (in Chinese)](https://datasheetspdf.com/pdf-file/684413/Mobicon/SW-180xx/1). I translated it but I can´t find an option to upload a PDF from my computer, only images. I´m trying to convert the translated text to JPG.

Comment: And you wish the solution to be simpler/cheaper than an accelerometer?

Comment: @JakobHalskov I guess the shake sensor could be the simplest and smallest way. I thought about a small accelerometer, but I lack space....

Comment: You forgot to make hyperlinks to the datasheets for the sensors in your question. Hit the edit link below your question ...

Comment: You must quantify your needs if you want an engineering solution. Saying things like "the slightest movement" or "a gentle tilt" or "really small" do not help. I expect that you probably have other constraints that you haven't told us, such as cost.

Comment: And what if I decide to lift it straight up at a glacial speed? You won't detect that either. Or push it sideways at a glacial speed? You need a more rigorous definition of what you want to detect. A gentle tilt is not a shake so I don't know why you would expect a shake sensor to detect one.

Comment: @Transistor Done. But some details are in chinese. Still trying to convert a translated version to jpg to upload later.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson Is just a home use thing, I need to lift my slave flash unit from the desk to take pictures, As long it´s in my hands, moving to take a picture, or even still in my hands (but our hands do move slightly even when trying to be still) I want it to detect this movement and keep the flashes on. When I put it  over a surface laying flat I want it to detect as completely still, and enter stand-by

Comment: Your requirements, as you have stated them, are impossible to fulfill using acceleration or "shaking". It is impossible to use these sensors to tell the difference between "still in my hands" and "completely still" if you can not tell us the minimum amount of acceleration that should be "not still". I think you should look for an entirely different detection mechanism.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson I see. Would those magnetometer sensors, or compass sensors, be more sensitive to tell if it´s completelly still or not? Something like those bubble meters apps for mobile phones? I´ll take readings from every 10 seconds, so, what´s important to me is that, when it´s completelly still for some time (a minute, for instance), it enters stand-by. If it detects changes in position in this interval, it keeps turned on. But I need it detects the flashes being taken from their still position to turn on.